How do I repair a sagging floor with a finished basement underneath?
Sagging Floor Question
I have a house with a sagging kitchen floor.  The ceramic tile is cracked and I can feel a slope towards the middle.   Underneath is a finished basement with drywall ceiling.  I want to have the flooring replaced in this kitchen anyway.  My question is....Does the repair need to be made from underneath, where I'd have to rip out the drywall ceiling in the finished basement below?  Or can repairs be made by removing some of the subfloor and doing it then when the flooring gets replaced?  Really hating the thought of destroying the ceiling on the finished basement.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

It can be done from above. But beware that a sagging floor is usually the type of job where you have to remove the whole subfloor, add joists, sister old joists, then install new subfloor, then floor covering and install floor molding. The decision of whether to remove or not the ceiling drywall is a minor issue in this context.
